# Solr gerando exceção "maxClauseCount is set to 1024"

Tags: apache-solr

Tenho um core do Apache Solr 4.0.0 que eu criei e que eventualmente gera a exceção:

```
SEVERE
SolrDispatchFilter
null:org.apache.lucene.search.BooleanQuery$TooManyClauses: maxClauseCount is set to 1024
```

E de fato existe uma configuração relacionada com a exceção, no config.xml do core:

```
<conf>
    ...
    <query>
        <maxBooleanClauses>1024</maxBooleanClauses>
        ...
    </query>
    ...
</conf>
```

Supostamente aumentar o valor de `1024` na configuração resolve, mas porque isto ocorre? E principalmente, como faço para alterá-la **sem refazer o core**?

Answer (score 1):

Dias depois descobri o problema e não está relacionado com `maxBooleanClauses` em `1024`. Pois quando consegui subir para `4096`, o Solr passou a gerar a mesma exceção só que alegando ter estourado as tais `4096` cláusulas booleanas.

A exceção era gerada pela definição do seguinte parâmetro na consulta: `hl.maxAnalyzedChars=1048576`, que estava, a princípio, com um valor muito alto. Exemplo de consulta que gera exceção:

```
http://10.10.5.86:8983/solr/sei-protocolos/select?q=%28+zaki+AND+abreu%29+AND+%28sta_protocolo%3AP+OR+sta_protocolo%3AR+OR+sta_protocolo%3AG%29+AND+%28tipo_acesso%3AP+OR+id_unidade_acesso%3A%2A1%2A%29&start=0&sort=dta_geracao+desc&hl=true&hl.snippets=2&hl.fl=content&hl.fragsize=100&hl.maxAnalyzedChars=1048576&hl.alternateField=content&hl.maxAlternateFieldLength=100&fl=id,tipo_acesso,id_unidade_acesso,id_unidade_geradora,id_unidade_aberto,identificacao_protocolo,nome_tipo_processo,protocolo_documento_formatado,protocolo_processo_formatado,sigla_unidade_geradora,descricao_unidade_geradora,sigla_usuario_gerador,nome_usuario_gerador,dta_geracao,link_arvore
```

Redefini o valor para `hl.maxAnalyzedChars=10000`, que é o valor de exemplo na documentação do Solr, e tudo passou a funcionar como o esperado. Exemplo de consulta que retorna o esperado:

```
http://10.10.5.86:8983/solr/sei-protocolos/select?q=%28+zaki+AND+abreu%29+AND+%28sta_protocolo%3AP+OR+sta_protocolo%3AR+OR+sta_protocolo%3AG%29+AND+%28tipo_acesso%3AP+OR+id_unidade_acesso%3A%2A1%2A%29&start=0&sort=dta_geracao+desc&hl=true&hl.snippets=2&hl.fl=content&hl.fragsize=100&hl.maxAnalyzedChars=10000&hl.alternateField=content&hl.maxAlternateFieldLength=100&fl=id,tipo_acesso,id_unidade_acesso,id_unidade_geradora,id_unidade_aberto,identificacao_protocolo,nome_tipo_processo,protocolo_documento_formatado,protocolo_processo_formatado,sigla_unidade_geradora,descricao_unidade_geradora,sigla_usuario_gerador,nome_usuario_gerador,dta_geracao,link_arvore
```